# Wrong shortest path using pg routing

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, osm2pgsql, osm2pgrouting

I want to find the shortest distance between two coordinates using pg routing. I am using Dijkstra algorithm but the shortest distance is incorrect. The correct value is approx. 6 km but I am getting 22km. I am attaching below the steps that were performed by me.

//Downloaded OpenStreetMap data file(North India) from https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/india.html

//installed the required extensions

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;
```

// created the topology using command:

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology('planet_osm_roads', 0.00001, 'way', 'osm_id');
```

// calculated the distance using :

```
SELECT
  sum(cost) AS distancem
FROM
  pgr_dijkstra(
    $$
      SELECT
        osm_id as id, source, target, ST_Length(way) as cost
      FROM
        planet_osm_roads
    $$,
    (
      SELECT
        source
      FROM
        planet_osm_roadsm
      ORDER BY
        ST_StartPoint(way) <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(28.460600130045364,77.05139982545913), 3857)
      LIMIT
        1
    ),
    (
      SELECT
        target
      FROM
        planet_osm_roads
      ORDER BY
        ST_EndPoint(way) <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(28.466847507495803,77.0932479947907), 3857)
      LIMIT
        1
    ),
    false
  );
```

I am getting the result:
22328.16439981528

But the actual result should be around 6000

Can someone please help

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Have you looked at the route on a map? can you show us a screen shot? most likely issue is that you have a missing segment and it is taking a longer route around the error

Comment: You have swapped latitude and longitude

Answer (score 9):

The two lookup points you pass into the *(K)NN* sub-queries can't be referenced in `EPSG:3857` - their coordinate values seem to be in *degree* and are likely `EPSG:4326`!

Assuming `planet_osm_roads.way` has been **projected to `EPSG:3857`** during import (or manually after), and the point coordinates are indeed **referenced in `EPSG:4326`**, you need to add a respective **projection step** to both the points you pass in, i.e.:

```
ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(<x>, <y>), 4326), 3857)
```

Note that finding the closest vertex (id) in the `planet_osm_roads_vertices` table instead (with similar *(K)NN* queries) would yield a better approximation of route start and end points in the network.

---

Make sure you understand the difference between *setting* a coordinate reference vs. *reprojecting* a coordinate reference.

Comment: @PiyushNarula did this solve your question/problem? If so, consider accepting the answer. If not, what issues are you facing?